# Reshaping Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

How do I reshape a numpy array ? The array that I want to reshape is called C4 and currently has a shape of:

C4 shape:  (606976,)

I want to rehsape it to (1,)

or I want to reshape an array of shape (1,) to shape (606976,). How do I go about doing this ?

Comment: I don't think you understand `reshape`.  `numpy` reshape has to preserve the total number of elements.  Thus you can reshape C4 to some combination of dimensions whose product match the original.  BUT, first, what's the `dtype` of this array?  And why the `(1,)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways -

- using reshape method

  ```
  c4 = c4.reshape(1, 606976)
  ```
- using transpose method

  ```
  c4 = c4.T
  ```